# Как узнать какие (несколько / все) версии Python есть на компьютере?

Tags: python

Я пытаюсь понять, как автоматически найти и вывести в консоли все версии python, которые присутствуют и обнаруживаются на компьютере (и в linux и в windows). Гугление показывает мне только те ответы, как узнать текущую установленную версию. Я подумал, что для этого должен быть ответ на Stackoverflow.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53312590/how-can-i-check-all-the-installed-python-versions-on-windows

Comment: Спасибо. Я не нашёл этот ответ, но он мне помог.

Comment: Если вам помог ответ с английского СО, а на русском СО такого ответа нет, то всячески приветствуется сделать свой ответ по смыслу такой же как на английском СО (можно вкратце) и с ссылкой на тот ответ.

Comment: Прямо настоящим ответом бы выдержку из английского СО добавить, ну да как хотите.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В рамках Linux

```
update-alternatives --config python
```

Вывод будет примерно таким:

```
There are 2 choices for the alternative python (providing /usr/bin/python).

  Selection    Path                      Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/local/bin/python3.8   2         auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/python3.6         1         manual mode
  2            /usr/local/bin/python3.8   2         manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

Answer (score 5):

Мне помог этот ответ на английском:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53312590/how-can-i-check-all-the-installed-python-versions-on-windows

> Which tells me that "-0" (zero, not letter "O") lists the available pythons:

```
C:\Users\admin>py -0
Installed Pythons found by py Launcher for Windows
 -3.7-64 *
 -3.7-32
 -2.7-64
 -2.7-32
```

В ответе указано, что утилита 'py' содержит параметр "-0" (это ноль, а не буква "О") специально для такого случая. Просто введите `py -0`